# Cart notification reminder linked to checkout in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, hook-woocommerce

In Woocommerce, I'm looking for a way to display a short message in homepage or any page when the cart have products to remind the user that it could complete the payment.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam." You need to do the proper research and see if you can find any plugin that does what you want. If you can't find any, you'll need to build your own.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following very simple code snippet will display a reminder (a woocommerce notice) when cart has items:

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'checkout_reminder');
function checkout_reminder() {
    // Not on checkout page
    if( ! WC()->cart->is_empty() && ! is_checkout() ){
        $link     = wc_get_checkout_url(); // Checkout Url
        $count    = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count(); // cart count

        // Add a notice
        wc_add_notice(  sprintf( __("You have %d item(s) in cart."), $count ) . ' ' .
            '<a href="' . $link . '" class="button">' . __("Go to checkout") . '</a>',
        'notice' );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme). tested and works.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much
So Can I customize where can I put this in my theme?

Comment: @GamalElwazeery As said before, this uses the Woocommerce notices api functionality, so you can't customize the location and *"code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme)"*. Thanks